# Dynamic charts with MVC and CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, charts, canvasjs

I am trying to generate a CanvasJS bar chart from an MVC model list.
this seems to generate the objects ok but when I try to render the chart canvasJS complains it cannot find the data array.any ideas please?

```
<script>
    var yearbargraphchart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerbar1");

    yearbargraphchart.options.title = {
        text: "Year attendance: " + " percent_attend var here " + " %",
        fontWeight: "bolder",
        fontColor: "#008B8B",
        fontSize: 20,
        padding: 10
    };

    yearbargraphchart.options.axisX = {
        title: "Axis X Title"
    };
    yearbargraphchart.options.axisY = {
        title: "Axis Y Title"
    };

    var fa = [];
    yearbargraphchart.data = fa;              
</script>


@foreach (var item in Model){
<script>
    var bp = [];
    var obj = {}
   obj.foo = "test";
   test = [];

 bp.push({ label: ' Present: ' + "@(item.Marks_present)" , y: "@(item.Marks_present)" });      

    var n = "dps@(item.Month)";            // set dynamic name for sub array:
    var test = { type: "bar", name: n };      
    test.dataPoints = bp;
    fa.push(test);

   console.log("post yearbargraphchart.data.push " + JSON.stringify(yearbargraphchart.data));
</script>
}

<script>
yearbargraphchart.render();
yearbargraphchart = {};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some data relation mistakes.

```
var fa = [];
yearbargraphchart.data = fa;
```

this doesn't actually  bind 'fa' to 'yearbargraphchart.data' so later when you do

```
fa.push(test);
```

you push the data in 'fa' which doesn't get pushed into 'yearbargraphchart.data'

try this. Instead

```
yearbargraphchart.data.push(test);
```

I think that will solve the problem